# Centering mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 labels and I want them to be in the middle. Angular Material provides simple class `mat-align-tabs="center"` which doesn't work at all. I searched an internet an found solutions for md, which is old version of Material. Surprised that nobody didn't face same problem.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex"  mat-align-tabs="center">
    <mat-tab id="Wyszuk" label="Wyszukiwanie" *ngIf="!leadOffer.isSent">
      <app-offer-search-candidates [offerId]="leadOffer.id" [leadId]="leadId" [offer]="leadOffer"
        [candidatesToVerification]="candidatesToVerificationDataSource.data" [awaitingCandidates]="awaitingCandidatesDataSource.data"
        (addCandidatesToVerification)="onAddCandidatesToVerification($event)" (addAwaitingCandidates)="onAddAwaitingCandidates($event)"
        (addCandidatesToCart)="onAddCandidatesToCart($event)" (searchSave)="onSearchSave($event)">
      </app-offer-search-candidates>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Koszyk ofertowy">
      <app-offer-cart [dataSource]="candidatesDataSource" [searchModel]="searchModel" [readOnly]="leadOffer.isSent"
        [attachmentsDataSource]="attachmentsDataSource" (refresh)="onRefreshCandidates()" (removeCandidates)="onRemoveCandidatesFromCart($event)"
        (sendOffer)="onSendOffer($event)" (removeAllCandidates)="onRemoveAllCandidates()" (removeCart)="onRemoveCart()"
        (generateOffer)="onGenerateOffer()" (attachmentsLoaded)="onAttachmentsLoaded($event)" (removeAttachments)="onRemoveAttachments($event)"
        (generateCvs)="onGenerateCvs($event)" (updateProjectRole)="onUpdateProjectRole($event)" (updateSuggestedPrice)="onUpdateSuggestedPrice($event)"
        (candidateCvLoaded)="onCandidateOfferCvLoaded($event)">
      </app-offer-cart>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image: Check this Image Out]

Comment: Is there a container which surrounds the mat-tab ?

Comment: using mat-align-tabs should work, please check the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#label-alignment

Comment: @liqSTAR no container is there.

Comment: @katwhocodes it should, but it doesn't. That's the problem.

Comment: Which angular version and material you are using?

Comment: @liqSTAR  Angular 6.1.0, Material 6.7.0

Comment: maybe it does not support the align in this version, try updating the style .mat-tab-labels { justify-content: center; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be a versioning problem. Tried it in Angular 6, not working. But with Angular 7, it is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-7-install-mat-tab-center

Angular 6:
Add this to your global stylesheet `style.scss`.

```
.mat-tab-labels {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

For more, read [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles). If you add it to the component.scss it will be overwritten, in the global not. Additional you can specify the component you want this style applied to.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-mat-tab-centered

Comment: Lemme try something.

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately this is really a version problem. By now I use ::ng-deep to force my styles. Appreciate your link!

Comment: What if you want the tabs to fill the whole width of the parent div? When I do this, it does get centered, but there are white spaces before the first and after the last tab.

Comment: Need to Check this. And try myself

Comment: And if you want to the hack do it right. Also add: ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    flex: 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

This works in Angular 10.0.1 if you want the content under your centered mat tabs in the center too.

```
::ng-deep mat-tab-body {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-labels {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This is working in angular 9 with scss.